# Output voltage of Class B Amplifier with global negative feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, pspice, orcad

For the following schematic on the non-inverting input is applied a sine wave.

Shouldn't be the output on R19 0.9 out of the input voltage, by using a voltage divider between R31 and R19. From my simulation the input signal and output signal are exactly the same.

This amp is the final part of a simulation of an audio amplifier.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: No, because R31 (and R30) are inside the feedback loop.

Comment: Is there any formula which can tell me what is the maximum value of this resistances so that the output won't be clipped?

Comment: Basically, Ohms Law.

Comment: My max output is 9V, from this results that the current through my output resistance is 0.45 A, but from here I don't know how to continue, from OrCad if both of my resistances (R30 and R31) are 8 ohms or greater, the output signal gets clipped.

Comment: First get the Voh (max) and Vol(min) for your opamp at +/-15V from its datasheet.. Then subtract Vbe (Q3.Q4) from these. Now you have the peak output voltages available. Subtract your max output voltage to get V(R30,R31). You already have I(out) : the rest is Ohms Law.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is directly connected to the inverting input of your opamp.  You have made a voltage follower.

Remember, an opamp will try to make its two input's voltage match.

Comment: Does it matter what values I give to the resistances: R31,R30? Because if I give large values like 1kOhm, the output is clipped.

Comment: It wont matter until you have changed them enough that the opamp cannot drive enough to keep up.

Comment: Is there any formula which can be used to compute the maximum values of the resistors so that the output signal won't be clipped?

Comment: Think about it like this:  The emitter of Q3 can't go much above 14 V.  Depending on what values you have for R31 and R19 (this does form a voltage divider) you can see how high your output can possibly go.  Once this is below the peak voltage of your input, you will start to see clipping.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how the calculations should be made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108340/discussion-between-tgarmp-and-evildemonic).